# Is there any way to Route path with question mark?

Tags: javascript, react-router-dom

I am defining my Route

`<Route path={['/test', '/test\\?foo=:id&bar=:id\\&zoo=:id']} component={Test} />`

When I enter URL `localhost:9000/test?foo=100&bar=100&zoo=100` its is not being redirected to Test component. I added `console.log(this.props.location.search)` in componentDidMount() but  it is giving output as `?foo=100&bar=100&zoo=100`

And it is going to my Error page view which is,

`<Route path="" component={ErrorPage} />`

I have tried to remove the Question mark (?) from URL and added characters like [, ], $ and the URL is hitting Test component.

Is there any way If I enter URL = `localhost:9000/test?foo=100&bar=100&zoo=100` I get redirected to Test component rather than going to an error component.

I would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass a `path` which contains question mark, but you have to parse that inside your component instead of the path. You have to install (or create your own) a proper tool to parse the query string. I suggest you to use the `query-string` one.

After that the route inside the routing file or whereever you use them should look like this:

```
<Route path="/test" component={Test} />
```

The `Test` component:

```
import React from 'react';
import queryString from 'query-string';

class Test extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { location: { search } } = this.props;
    const values = queryString.parse(search);
    // Use the values to whatever you want.
  }

  render() {
    {/* ... */}
  }
}
```

Inside the above example, the values will contains your query string parameters, for example if the url is that you provided: `localhost:9000/test?foo=100&bar=100&zoo=100` the values will be:

```
{
  foo: 100,
  bar: 100,
  zoo: 100
}
```

Comment: Ty for your answer @knightburton.

Comment: @TEMP no worries, mate